# The given origin is not allowed for the given client ID (GSI)

Tags: javascript, google-signin

I was refactoring my "Sign in with Google" by replacing `gapi` with `gsi` on `http://localhost:8080`.

How can `gapi` work without problems while `gsi` claims that `The given origin is not allowed for the given client ID`.

[image]

### gapi

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api:client.js" async defer></script>
```

```js
window.gapi.load('auth2', () => {
  const auth2 = window.gapi.auth2.init({ client_id })
  auth2.signIn().then(console.log)
})
```

### gsi

```
<script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async defer></script>
```

```html
<div id="g_id_onload"
     :data-client_id="client_id"
     data-login_uri="http://localhost:8080"
     data-auto_prompt="false">
</div>
<div class="g_id_signin"
     data-type="standard"
     data-size="large"
     data-theme="outline"
     data-text="sign_in_with"
     data-shape="rectangular"
     data-logo_alignment="left">
</div>
```

Errors out with: `The given origin is not allowed for the given client ID`

Comment: Have the same issue. What is interesting is that I turned off any ad-blocker and suddenly the error disappeared and the POST request appeared at my end point as expected. Can you confirm this behavior? I have ABP, uBlock Origin, uBlock, and Ad-Blocker. I noticed there were several failed resources in my console and perhaps this may be a serious issue underlying the GSI framework or perhaps my adblocking.

Comment: On similar lines, it fails in normal mode but works fine in Incognito mode.

Comment: @Jack I have this issue, I turned off all my ad-blockers (ublock origin, and AdBlock) and still have the issue.

Answer (score 384, accepted):

I added origin without port to fix this issue.

> **Key Point**: Add both **http://localhost** and **http://localhost:<port_number>** to the **Authorized JavaScript origins** box for local tests or development.

Source: https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/get-google-api-clientid

Comment: Hi @Crow, I added the both things, but it does work for me. Would you give me a suggestion? Currently I have a urgent problem with that.

Comment: @Venus713 Check if your development URL is exactly the same. You might be using https, so it might be something like `https://localhost:8080` and `https://localhost`. You should also check if you are using correct Client ID.

Comment: @Venus713 I have the same problem in Chrome browser - both http://localhost and http://localhost:8080 are added to Authorized JavaScript origins, and Client ID is correct, but still the same error. 
However, the same code works in incognito mode.

Comment: A quick tip for those who may try everything else with no chance:
It's good to keep in mind that for some reason, 127.0.0.1 doesn't work and would keep showing this error, even if you register it in your Google Dashboard. But as soon as you use localhost instead, it starts working.

Comment: Thank you for this tip. I was getting crazy over this issue, since everything was set up as explaine. But additional adding localhost without the port was something i never would have considered. Thanks so much for this :)

Comment: Thanks for sharing this useful tip for setting up local environment testing.

Comment: You are a LEGEND

Comment: Hi, I've tried your method on locohost and it works. But after I hosted it on AWS S3 it failed again.  Do you have any ideas? I already add the s3 endpoint to "Authorised JavaScript origins".

Comment: Adding both the domains is the key solution... Thanks buddy!

Answer (score 43):

This can also happen if your server has `Referrer-Policy` set to `no-referrer`. Google requires this HTTP header or else requests to https://accounts.google.com/gsi/button and https://accounts.google.com/gsi/iframe/select will respond with 400 and produce that error

If using helmet - the following config will fix the request

```
referrerPolicy: {
  policy: 'strict-origin-when-cross-origin'
}
```

[MDN article for Referrer-Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referrer-Policy)

Comment: You're my hero! I have a Gatsby website hosted on Netlify, and the default `Referrer-Policy` header there is `same-origin`. Setting that to `strict-origin-when-cross-origin` solved it - this saved me a lot of headache!

Comment: Wow... can't believe this was not mentioned anywhere else. Solved my problem
In Django it means setting `SECURE_REFERRER_POLICY = "strict-origin-when-cross-origin"` in settings

Comment: How do I set this in Laravel ?

Comment: I'd like to try it, but I don't know how to use it for Javascript/Reactjs.

Comment: upvoted, it helps, 400 issue solved, but now getting 
(blocked:CoepFrameResourceNeedsCoepHeader)

Comment: `crossOriginEmbedderPolicy: false` setting this to helmet fixed the issue

Comment: @MartinWedvich can you kindly explain how and where you set Referrer Policy? I have the same issue on Gatsby + Gatsby Cloud.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know how you'd do it for Gatsby Cloud, but this is where I set it for Netlify in my `gatsby-config.js`:

```js
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-plugin-netlify',
      options: {
        headers: {
          '/*': ['Referrer-Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin'],
        },
        mergeLinkHeaders: false,
      },
    },
```

Comment: When using `localhost` for development, the GSI docs say to set `Referrer-Policy` to `no-referrer-when-downgrade`; this was the final missing piece for me.

Comment: Setting `SECURE_REFERRER_POLICY = "strict-origin-when-cross-origin"` in django's `settings.py` solved it for me

Comment: A way to set this header is to do so on the index.html Head: 

```<meta name="referrer" content="strict-origin-when-cross-origin">```

Answer (score 30):

I got faced with same issue. For some reason, none of the solutions discussed here did it for me.
I got it solved by adding these to the Authorized Origins in the Google cloud console

- http://localhost
- http://localhost:<port_number>

Comment: So weird, I had to add `http://localhost` even though I was on port 3000 too!  Great catch!  Saved me a lot of time.

Comment: Oh, man. Thanks. It's really weird but it works! If not you, I believe I would stuck here for days...

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you!

Answer (score 21):

A comment from @Behzad that deserves it's own answer:

**For some reason, 127.0.0.1 will not work, even if you register it in your Google Dashboard.**

But as soon as you use **localhost** instead, it starts working.

I was using Live Server for VSCode, and had to look up how to change the host it was serving on.

Go to Code > Preferences > Settings > Live Server Config > Host and change it to local host.
[image]

Then make sure localhost is registered in your Google Dashboard:
[image]

Comment: Hero. 

I had to make these origin changes and also change my Flask app run code to:

`if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=debug, host="localhost")`

Comment: I don't know how Google doesn't have this explained clearly in their Docs. HERO Joshua

Answer (score 11):

Found a solution while testing this as I was encountering the following error messages related to this one despite adding the site domain to the `Authorised JavaScript origins`:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 ()

> [GSI_LOGGER]: The given origin is not allowed for the given client ID.

If you're using a domain name that is not `localhost`, make sure that you are accessing your site via `https` (using a self-signed certificate if a certificate is not yet available / if testing in your non-prod environment).

Comment: This was this! Thank you. I've used 127.0.0.1 and added both localhost and 127.0.0.1 but it wasnt working. When entered via localhost. It's fine!

Answer (score 10):

Based on their documentation it says;

> When you perform local tests or development, you must add both http://localhost and http://localhost:<port_number> to the Authorized JavaScript origins box. The Referrer-Policy header must also be set to no-referrer-when-downgrade when using http and localhost.

on your case, it seems like you need to add `no-referrer-when-downgrade` directives of rendered button

Answer (score 2):

For my live app I needed both `https://example.com` and `https://www.example.com` to be set as origins

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue with Django 4.2.x, updating the [`SECURE_CROSS_ORIGIN_OPENER_POLICY`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#secure-cross-origin-opener-policy) attribute of `django.conf.settings` to `unsafe-none` and [`SECURE_REFERRER_POLICY`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#secure-referrer-policy) to `strict-origin-when-cross-origin`  solved the issue for me.

```py
# my_project/settings.py
SECURE_REFERRER_POLICY = "strict-origin-when-cross-origin"
SECURE_CROSS_ORIGIN_OPENER_POLICY = "same-origin-allow-popups"
```

Answer (score 0):

i hope this helps someone
*if you are on django *
add this to your settings.py

`SECURE_CROSS_ORIGIN_OPENER_POLICY='same-origin-allow-popups'`

Answer (score 0):

Head to your Google OAuth 2.0 Client IDs in the credential dashboard and click the edit button, in the Authorized JavaScript origins add `http://localhost` and note it doesn't have the port.