# [GSI_LOGGER]: The given origin is not allowed for the given client ID

Tags: django-allauth, google-one-tap

I am trying to integrate the google-one-tap with my django project on my localhost.
So I added `http://localhost:8000` and `http://localhost` into the *Authorized JavaScript origins* in *Client ID for Web application*.
I read some blogs that the above setting does work for the google-one-tap local testing, but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: I am in the same boat and wanted to tell you that your setup is correct. There were recent changes that are "perhaps" preventing usage of "localhost" as origin. When the service was only called "Sign-In" we were able to use "localhost" as origin but not "127.0.0.1".

Answer (score 8):

Answer provided here worked for me: [The given origin is not allowed for the given client ID (GSI)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68438293/the-given-origin-is-not-allowed-for-the-given-client-id-gsi)

As ridiculous as it seems omitting the port and writing `http://localhost` as JavaScript origin makes the new Google Identity Services code work.

Now my next question is how this change will affect the redirect url, which also accepted a port before.

Comment: Quite ridiculous. Omitting the port actually worked. :D

Answer (score 7):

I finally found out the solution.

It should be set the **SECURE_REFERRER_POLICY** in the **settings.py** like this.

```
SECURE_REFERRER_POLICY = "no-referrer-when-downgrade"
```

Answer (score 2):

Add both `http://localhost` and `http://localhost:<port_number>` to the Authorized JavaScript origins box for `local tests or development`. [Read more](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/get-google-api-clientid)

Answer (score 0):

The setup is correct according to the setup instructions [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/get-google-api-clientid).

Aside from following the above document, please also make sure you are sending the requests from the correct origin. In your case it should be from http://localhost:8000. Please also double check to see if the HTTP headers and parameters in the request also match the authorized origins.

Would you be able to find out which request failed from the web console?

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.