# Using Google Identity Service to create a sign up button but nothing is displayed in popup window

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, google-signin

When I click on the "sign up with google button" nothing is displayed on the pop-up window.

I have gone through some of the previous posts in SO but they didn't fix this issue:

**Links Visited**

- [the-given-origin-is-not-allowed-for-the-given-client-id-gsi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68438293/the-given-origin-is-not-allowed-for-the-given-client-id-gsi)
- [gsi-logger-the-given-origin-is-not-allowed-for-the-given-client-id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68854740/gsi-logger-the-given-origin-is-not-allowed-for-the-given-client-id)

**Here is the output :**

[image: Pop up window]

**This the JS Authorized Origin Configuration**

[image: Authorized Origin Image]

I'm using `Django` as *backend* and here is the code to display the `google sign up button` :

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async defer></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="g_id_onload" data-client_id="client_id" data-context="signup" data-ux_mode="popup" data-login_uri="http://localhost:8000/users/register/signinWithGoogle" data-nonce="" data-auto_prompt="false">
  </div>

  <div class="g_id_signin" data-type="standard" data-shape="rectangular" data-theme="outline" data-text="signup_with" data-size="large" data-logo_alignment="left">
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

**Django `settings.py` configuration :**

```
SECURE_REFERRER_POLICY = "no-referrer-when-downgrade"

CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
CSRF_COOKIE_SAMESITE = 'None'
SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE = 'None'
```

Why is the "sign up with google" button not working am I missing something and how we can fix it?

Comment: I tested your signin button and it works fine for me.    The error message implies that you have not set the Javascript origin correctly but http://localhost:8000 should be correct are you sure you put it on the correct client in the correct project?

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo what do you mean by correct client in the correct project can you please elaborate?

Comment: When I switch to `developer mode` on the popup window(SignUp With Google) its displaying this error message `m=credential_page_library:45 [GSI_LOGGER]: The given origin is not allowed for the given client ID.`

Comment: origin is the javascript origin.   Your app appers sto be running from localhost:8000 which would mean that you should be able to add localhost:8000 or just localhost which i can see you have done.   Making me think maybe your changing it on the wrong client.

Comment: If more details from me let me know I will update the answer

Comment: now instead of 127.0.0.1 I'm using localhost and now its showing `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'postMessage')
    at Ei (m=credential_page_library:202:183)`
in the popup window

Comment: @devp Go to the Google Developers Console.
Select the project associated with your API client ID.
Go to the "Credentials" page.
Locate the API client ID you are using in your code.
Click on the "Edit" button next to the API client ID.
In the "Authorized JavaScript origins" section, add the origin (URL) of your website where the Google Sign-In integration is located.
Save the changes.

Comment: What's displayed under the `Console` tab? Do you have any extensions, VPN, adblockers, PiHole, etc?

Comment: Can you share the entire URL from the sign-in popup?

Comment: `https://accounts.google.com/gsi/select?client_id=mine_client_id&ux_mode=popup&ui_mode=card&context=signin&as=6tu%2Bpcu8BxQtCcYkJS7Htw&channel_id=900ae4df16409775cb8bcd203f0c39324fe0fa8aad457d8329148223623a0e1f&origin=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8000`

Comment: I have replaced my client id with mine_client_id

Answer (score 4):

If you don't mind using `Javascript` for your Google Sign In, you can follow these steps that I had to undertake to achieve the entire flow. You would also need to add your `localhost` to the Authorized origins which I believe you are doing.:

First create a `button` that will hold the `HTML` element:

```
<button id="btnGoogleSignIn" style="border:none;background: none;"> </button>
```

You can then use the below script and associated functions in which I am getting the  JWT token from Google and then decoding it to get the required information out like email address etc. Note that I am calling the onSignInGSI as callback on the button initialization.

```
<script>  
    function decodeJwtResponseFromGoogleAPI(token) {
            let base64Url = token.split('.')[1]
            let base64 = base64Url.replace(/-/g, '+').replace(/_/g, '/');
            let jsonPayload = 
           decodeURIComponent(atob(base64).split('').map(function (c) {
                return '%' + ('00' + 
           c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)).slice(-2);
            }).join(''));
            return JSON.parse(jsonPayload)
        }

    function onSignInGSI(response) {
        //console.log(response)
        responsePayload = decodeJwtResponseFromGoogleAPI(response.credential);
        console.log("ID: " + responsePayload.sub);
        console.log('Full Name: ' + responsePayload.name);
        console.log('Given Name: ' + responsePayload.given_name);
        console.log('Family Name: ' + responsePayload.family_name);
        console.log("Image URL: " + responsePayload.picture);
        console.log("Email: " + responsePayload.email);
    }

    window.onload = function () {

        google.accounts.id.initialize({
            client_id: client_id,
            context: 'signin',
            callback: onSignInGSI
        });

        google.accounts.id.prompt((notification) => {
             if (notification.isNotDisplayed() || notification.isSkippedMoment()) {
               document.cookie =  `g_state=;path=/;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT`;
               google.accounts.id.prompt()
            }
         });
        
        google.accounts.id.renderButton(document.getElementById("btnGoogleSignIn"), 
        {
            type: "standard",
            text: "signin_with",
            logo_alignment: "left",
            width: 375
        });
    };
</script>
<script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async defer></script>
```

For more configuration options on the button you can refer [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/reference/js-reference#google.accounts.id.renderButton):

Comment: isn't this technique is deprecated we can't use this technique in future?

Comment: @devp This is the new technique which uses the GSI library. The old technique uses the platform.js library which is being deprecated.

Comment: I tried this method I'm getting this error in my Javascript console it also generated in previous code `Indicate whether to send a cookie in a cross-site request by specifying its SameSite attribute
Because a cookie’s SameSite attribute was not set or is invalid, it defaults to SameSite=Lax, which prevents the cookie from being sent in a cross-site request. This behavior protects user data from accidentally leaking to third parties and cross-site request forgery.
Specify SameSite=Strict or SameSite=Lax if the cookie should not be sent in cross-site requests.
18 cookies`

Comment: When I press google signIn button the dialog pops up but nothing is displayed and in console this error message is generated `client:110          POST https://accounts.google.com/gsi/log?client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID&as=77esRGA2kLL2lppDXuIEzg&event=onetap.closed.buttonFlowStarted net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT`

Comment: @devp I have my updated answer in the `google.accounts.id.prompt` function. You should also try clearing out your cookies on the development environment.

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'postMessage')
    at Ki (m=credential_page_library:201:183)
    at Li (m=credential_page_library:201:105)
    at _.Pi.i (m=credential_page_library:203:342)
    at _.uj.i (m=credential_page_library:211:947)
    at Object.bootstrap (m=credential_page_library:348:68)
    at select?client_id=my_client_id&ux_mode=popup&ui_mode=card&context=signin&as=llc7zFJCPS1G/%2BNy9boj%2Bw&channel_id=54e263e7e0620ba9574113bcb48a1badaeac275d302967691cbd5a4aa5879e8c&origin=http://localhost:8000&authuser=0:4:513`

Comment: after I clear by browser and tried to login to pop window with my google account its showing black screen and the error message generated on the console of the pop up window is mentioned above

Comment: Now when I try to login for `second time` its just showing the black screen on the popup window and the same error message mentioned on the `3rd` and `4th` comment.

Comment: @devp Are you running your localhost on http or https? Can you trying running on https. I think google is blocking the request because of SSL error

Comment: @devp Your 3rd comment (related to cookie) is related to server side setting of cookie which you should remove on the development environment and should only be set on production environment

Comment: I will test google sigin on https for that I have to deploy my application to the server and within some days I will do that.

Comment: for the project Using `django` as the backend framework and I have set `cookies` but its still showing these errors. These are the settings for the project backend server `SECURE_REFERRER_POLICY = "no-referrer-when-downgrade"

CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
CSRF_COOKIE_SAMESITE = 'None'
SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE = 'None'`

Comment: @devp Have you tried removing this configuration on your server side and then try on localhost? When you deploy on production environment with `https` then it should work without any problems since I have tried and tested this myself on live sites.

Comment: Yes I have tested without these settings and it showed more error messages `Failed to load responded with a status of 400 m=credential_button_library:45 [GSI_LOGGER]: The given origin is not allowed for the given client ID. @ m=credential_button_library:45
accounts.google.com/gsi/iframe/select?client_id=my_client_id_here&ux_mode=popup&ui_mode=card&context=signin&as=long_msg&channel_id=some_id_here&origin=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8000:1          Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400
accounts.google.com/gsi/log?client_id=my_client_id_here&::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT`

Comment: I had to reduce the error message generated cause it was too long and the replaced my original client id with my_client_id

Comment: @devp As per Google documentation: https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/get-google-api-clientid#get_your_google_api_client_id , you need to set the `Referrer-Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade ` header when testing using http and localhost.

Comment: I have set this variable in the server `SECURE_REFERRER_POLICY = "no-referrer-when-downgrade"`

Comment: @devp Do you see any errors when you try in incognito mode.?

Comment: In Incognito it shows the same error msg.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251832/discussion-between-rahul-sharma-and-devp).

Answer (score 1):

from the details you had mentioned, Auth code flow failed as soon as it started due to unauthorized origin.

As per the message "m=credential_page_library:45 [GSI_LOGGER]: The given origin is not allowed for the given client ID" you had mentioned,
you need to add "http://localhost:8000/users/register/signinWithGoogle" to authorized javascript origins.

Also you need to validate that client id you are using is correct.

Comment: We can't add `http://localhost:8000/users/register/signinWithGoogle` to the authorized URL list its giving error `Invalid origin: URIs must not contain a path or end with '/'.`

Answer (score 1):

The error occurs for apps with "Publishing Status = In production" when your "Authorized JavaScript origin" does not start with `https://` but with `http://`.

- `http://my.server.name:8000` is not accepted, a message is shown:

  > Invalid Origin: This app has a publishing status of "In production". URI must use https:// as the scheme.
- `http://localhost:8000` shows no such message, but still leads to the error.
- `https://my.server.name:8000` works.

Strangely, when "Publishing Status = Testing", the behavior is the same, except that the message for `http://my.server.name:8000` does not appear.

(The Publishing Status of an app is maintained in the Google Cloud console under "APIs and Services > OAuth consent screen".)

Comment: Show we can't test the google signup and google login with http ?

Comment: Try switching the Publishing status back to "In Testing".

Comment: Publishing status is in testing.

Comment: Indeed, that seems to make (almost) no difference.

Comment: Perhaps related to https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/179172843.