# React Google Identity services

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-identity

I have been trying to implement Google's identity services API in my React app, but couldn't get it to work.

I'm trying to implement the following really simple JS code: https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/display-button#javascript

What I came up with is the following:

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    //I'm adding the <script>
    const elemScript = document.createElement('script'); 
    elemScript.src = "https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client";
    elemScript.async = true;
    elemScript.defer = true;
    document.body.append(elemScript);

    //adding the code from the documentation
    window.onload = function () {
      /*global google*/
      console.log(google)
      google.accounts.id.initialize({
        client_id: "<don't worry, I put the ID here>",
        callback: handleCredentialResponse
      });
      google.accounts.id.renderButton(
        googleButton.current, //this is a ref hook to the div in the official example
        { theme: "outline", size: "large" }  // customization attributes
      );
    }

    return () => {
      //I get ride of the <scripts> when the elements is unmounted
      document.body.removeChild(elemScript);
    }
  }, [])

  //This is my main and only objective, to get the token...
  function handleCredentialResponse(response) {
    console.log("Encoded JWT ID token: " + response.credential);
  }

  return (
    <div ref={googleButton}></div>
  )
}

export default GoogleAuth
```

<s>When I call this component in my main App it sometimes renders the button, sometimes it doesn't (and the cause of this seems to be react-router-dom as it won't load if I'm moving from another page in my domain to where the button is). And even when I get the render I get errors and I can't login.</s>

Thanks to Bogdanof's answer solved the problem of the button only appearing sometimes through the use of Promises.

Now my only problem is the following:

`[GSI_LOGGER]: The given origin is not allowed for the given client ID.`

I have made and ID OAuth2.0 on Google only for this App. I enabled http://localhost:3000 as it's JS origin (and the same for the URIs), but I'm still getting that answer. I tried changing browsers and even deleting my cache and cookies as I read that it may help, but nothing worked.

Someone has any ideas about how to solve this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Hey so I got the final result, the following code doesn't has any problem with rendering the button thanks to the use of Promises (again thanks bogdanoff for his help with this):

```
//External imports
import { useEffect, useRef } from 'react'

  const loadScript = (src) =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (document.querySelector(`script[src="${src}"]`)) return resolve()
    const script = document.createElement('script')
    script.src = src
    script.onload = () => resolve()
    script.onerror = (err) => reject(err)
    document.body.appendChild(script)
  })

const GoogleAuth = () => {

  const googleButton = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const src = 'https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client'
    const id = "< your ID here ;) >"

    loadScript(src)
      .then(() => {
        /*global google*/
        console.log(google)
        google.accounts.id.initialize({
          client_id: id,
          callback: handleCredentialResponse,
        })
        google.accounts.id.renderButton(
          googleButton.current, 
          { theme: 'outline', size: 'large' } 
        )
      })
      .catch(console.error)

    return () => {
      const scriptTag = document.querySelector(`script[src="${src}"]`)
      if (scriptTag) document.body.removeChild(scriptTag)
    }
  }, [])

  function handleCredentialResponse(response) {
    console.log("Encoded JWT ID token: " + response.credential);
  }

  return (
    <div ref={googleButton}></div>
  )
}

export default GoogleAuth
```

Then for solving the OAuth problem I found the solution here in Crow's answer: [The given origin is not allowed for the given client ID (GSI)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68438293/the-given-origin-is-not-allowed-for-the-given-client-id-gsi)

Basically add http://localhost without a port to your origins (dunno why gsi needs this, but it needs it)

Hope this helps someone

Comment: The reason why I put `loadScript` function outside `GoogleAuth` component is react will call `GoogleAuth` component (function) on every single render thus if you keep `loadScript` inside this component it will be defined and deleted on every single render. So keep `loadSrc`  outside since it  doesn't need any variables from  `GoogleAuth` component or better in keep separate file if you want use it in multiple components.

Answer (score 5):

you can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-oauth/google, and you can check the implementation https://github.com/MomenSherif/react-oauth if you want to implement on your own

Comment: Great work. keep it up.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't tested this but have applied this technique in past.

```js
const loadScript = (src) =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (document.querySelector(`script[src="${src}"]`)) return resolve()
    const script = document.createElement('script')
    script.src = src
    script.onload = () => resolve()
    script.onerror = (err) => reject(err)
    document.body.appendChild(script)
  })

function GoogleAuth() {
  useEffect(() => {
    const src = 'https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client'

    loadScript(src)
      .then(() => {
        console.log(google)
        google.accounts.id.initialize({
          client_id: "<don't worry, I put the ID here>",
          callback: handleCredentialResponse,
        })
        google.accounts.id.renderButton(
          googleButton.current, //this is a ref hook to the div in the official example
          { theme: 'outline', size: 'large' } // customization attributes
        )
      })
      .catch(console.error)

    return () => {
      const scriptTag = document.querySelector(`script[src="${src}"]`)
      if (scriptTag) document.body.removeChild(scriptTag)
    }
  }, [])

  //This is my main and only objective, to get the token...
  function handleCredentialResponse(response) {
    console.log('Encoded JWT ID token: ' + response.credential)
  }

  return <div ref={googleButton}></div>
}

export default GoogleAuth
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! Your code solved the problem of the button appearing only sometimes (I had to add /*global google*/ because of eslint but it worked perfectly). Thanks again for the help

Answer (score 2):

I just simply import the script at CDN

```html
<script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async defer></script>
```

and use the `google` global variable but if you are using `typescript`, put the `google` var on global declaration

```js
// ./global.d.ts
export {};

declare global {
  const google: any;
}
```

for `typings` I refer this [blog](https://dev.to/mremanuel/add-the-new-google-sign-in-to-your-react-app-p6m)