# [GSI_LOGGER]: The given origin is not allowed for given client ID. Although my domain is authorised JS origin

Tags: google-signin, google-identity, react-google-login

I've implemented **`Google OAuth2`** using the new Google Identity Services SDK using React `@react-oauth/google`, but it throws this error.

> ***[GSI_LOGGER]: The given origin is not allowed for the given client ID.***

[image]

Authorized JS Origin and Authorised Redirect URIs.

It is working fine locally but not working on the dev server.
The
Google sign in Button appears and is functional but the style props which I'm passing are failing and giving `400 code` below is the request URL:
[https://accounts.google.com/gsi/button?type=standard&theme=outline&size=large&text=undefined&shape=pill&logo_alignment=left&width=311px&locale=undefined&click_listener=undefined&client_id=%5C*%5C*%5C*%5C*%5C*%5C*%5C*%5C*%5C*%5C*%5C*%5C*%5C*%5C*%5C*%5C*%5C*%5C\](https://accounts.google.com/gsi/button?type=standard&theme=outline&size=large&text=undefined&shape=pill&logo_alignment=left&width=311px&locale=undefined&click_listener=undefined&client_id=%5C*%5C*%5C*%5C*%5C*%5C*%5C*%5C*%5C*%5C*%5C*%5C*%5C*%5C*%5C*%5C*%5C*%5C%5C)*

package which i'm using = https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-oauth/google.
**NOTE:** I'm not using customised google button , i'm using the normal one and passing (theme, width, size, shape etc.) as props

I'm expecting the same behaviour as local , functional and all the style props working .

Comment: I have the same problem, no matter how many times I check to make sure the domain added to authorized Authorized JavaScript origins

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to add this in HTML head

```
<head>   
   <meta name="referrer" content="origin">
</head>
```

More info:
[Origin is "not allowed" for given client ID when origin was added](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74612587/origin-is-not-allowed-for-given-client-id-when-origin-was-added)