# Sign in with Google using Google Identity Services gives a blank popup screen when using domain name other than localhost

Tags: html, node.js, web, google-api, backend

I am working on a website. To login the users, I am using the Sign in With Google button using Google Identity Services. It was working perfectly on localhost, however, as soon as I executed the code on a remote server and tried to access the domain from a browser on another computer, it shows a blank popup screen. The server log shows no error. I checked the browser console and it gives 2 errors which are as follows -->

> *Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 ()*
> *[GSI_LOGGER]: The given origin is not allowed for the given client ID.*

[image]

I have followed all the fixes given here: ***[The given origin is not allowed for the given client ID (GSI)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68438293/the-given-origin-is-not-allowed-for-the-given-client-id-gsi)***
to the best of my knowledge, however, have still not been able to fix this problem.
Could someone please guide me as i am fairly new to this.
This is my code, where i have tried to change the headers in NodeJS.

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please edit your question and include [example] not images of your code

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.