# Google Sign In stopped working - auth response not provided due to unknown_reason

Tags: google-oauth

We use the [new version of Sign In with Google for Web](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/overview) for authentication in our React application, and a few days ago sign in began failing for my account with the below errors from the One Tap prompt callback.

This happens exclusively on Google Chrome (tested & repro'ed on Chrome versions 112.0.5615.137 and 112.0.5615.59), and exclusively for my Google account - sign in works other browsers, the issue persists across browser instances (fresh Chrome install, older Chrome version on a different laptop) and environments (localhost, QA, Prod), and no one else can reproduce it with their Google accounts. We haven't changed the application code in months.

Console errors from the Google Sign In client:

```
[GSI_LOGGER]: Check credential status returns invalid response.
GET https://accounts.google.com/gsi/status?client_id=<googleappclientid>&as=<userid> net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
```

[Prompt Moment Notification](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/reference/js-reference#PromptMomentNotification) values on error:

```ts
res.isNotDisplayed() // true
res.getNotDisplayedReason() // "unknown_reason"
```

I'm unable to debug much in the minified script code but the user data looks unremarkable and the credentials response coming back seems to be empty.

This doesn't seem like an application code issue given the symptoms but for context our integration code looks something like:

*GSI initialization*

```ts
window.google.accounts.id.initialize({
  client_id: GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
  auto_select: true,
  callback: async ({ credential: jwtToken }: CredentialResponse) => {
    // handle jwtToken etc
  }),
});
```

*One Tap Button rendering*

```ts
window.google.accounts.id.renderButton(
  signInButtonParentRef.current,
  { type: "standard", theme: "filled_blue" },
  () => {
    prompt();
  }
);
```

*Prompt Callback*

```ts
const prompt = () => {
    window.google?.accounts.id.prompt((res: PromptMomentNotification) => {
      if (res.isNotDisplayed()) { 
          // ...handle response, show error
      }
    });
}
```

Troubleshooting steps done so far:

- Restarted Chrome & laptop, cleared cookies, localstorage, browser history, uninstalled and reinstalled Chrome
- Test on separate laptop/older Chrome version (reproduced)
- Reviewed Google account for anything odd
- Reviewed Authorized JavaScript origins settings for Google client
- Removed access to our application from Google Sign In (which is then restored upon auth attempt)
- Tested on other browsers (works on Safari, Firefox) and for other users (works for everyone else on Chrome)

Comment: Do you have the 1Password extension installed? I noticed this exact same issue after installing the 1Password extension. https://1password.community/discussion/139709/latest-chrome-extension-breaks-google-sign-in-on-our-website

Comment: @dillon that did it, thank you! Uninstalling 1password from Chrome works, as does the workaround described in https://1password.community/discussion/139709/latest-chrome-extension-breaks-google-sign-in-on-our-website to disable 1password extension pop-up blocking settings

Answer (score 2):

This issue was caused by the 1Password Chrome extension, as documented in [this 1Password support article](https://1password.community/discussion/139709/latest-chrome-extension-breaks-google-sign-in-on-our-website). It can be resolved by uninstalling the 1Password Chrome extension or following these steps to disable the setting in question:

1. Right click on 1Password icon in Chrome -> Menu (hamburger icon) -> Settings
2. Scroll down to the Autofill section
3. Toggle "Stop competing sign-in popups in the browser" off

An application code workaround described in the same article is to switch from the One Tap button to a Sign In with Google Button by rendering a div with a `class` attribute of `g_id_signin` (as described in the [Google Sign In docs](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/reference/html-reference#element_with_class_g_id_signin)). This does appear to work as well, but alters the UI/UX of the sign-in flow somewhat.

Comment: I have no 1Password Chrome extension installed but I got this error

Comment: @Charlesliam see if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/a/68469319/2183395