# Sign in with Google using GSI fails with "The given origin is not allowed for the given client ID" error

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-signin, vue-composition-api

I am trying to implement the sign in with google feature in my VueJs application. However, upon mount, I get two errors;

- Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 ()
- [GSI_LOGGER]: The given origin is not allowed for the given client ID.

I have double checked the clientId and I am 100% sure I am passing the correct ID.

I have also ensured that I have added http://localhost:8080 and http://localhost to the list of authorised javascript origins.

I simply cant understand why I am getting this error.

The VueJs code is

```
<script setup>
import { onMounted, ref } from 'vue'

const googleButton = ref(null)

onMounted(() => {
  google.accounts.id.initialize({
    client_id: "734095511167-hbu1na03bb2po3qc886ut75p6ae538sb.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    use_fedcm_for_prompt: true,
    callback: (response) => {
      console.log(response)
    }
  })

  google.accounts.id.renderButton(googleButton.value, {})
})
</script>
```

I have imported the GSI scripts in the index.html file within the head section (also tried from within body just for wtf's sake)

```
<script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client"></script>
```

[image: javascript origins]

[image: Errors]

Answer (score 2):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70739451/6473458) on a similar question helped me find a solution to the problem.

What I did is, I added a meta tag within the head section of my index.html file that specified the required referrer policy. (**SOLUTION**)

**`<meta name="referrer" content="strict-origin-when-cross-origin" />`**

This solved the problem. Before that, I had this set to no-referrer (as below)

`<meta name="referrer" content="no-referrer" />`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).