# credential_page_library:48 [GSI_LOGGER]: The given origin is not allowed for the given client ID

Tags: javascript, php, google-oauth, google-signin, lamp

I am trying to get google oauth working on my php webapp.
I'm in dev, on a centos LAMP environment with a URL that is configured to `http://centos-myapp.com` via `/etc/hosts` on Windows.

On `https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials/oauthclient` I have set up a clientid for my app using the `http://centos-myapp.com` [Authorised Javascript orgins] URL,

and a dummy Authorised redirect URIs url to `http::/localhost/index.php` (as I can't seem to use http://centos-myapp.com ... as it wanted https)

When I run the http://centos-myapp.com page - I see the "Sign in with Google" button from the g_id_onload structure

```
 <div id='g_id_onload'
      data-client_id='$google_clientId'
      data-login_uri='http://centos-myapp.com'
      data-auto_prompt='false'>
 </div>
 <div class='g_id_signin'
       data-type='$googleLoginType'
       data-size='$googleLoginSize'
       data-theme='$googleLoginTheme'
       data-text='$googleLoginText'
       data-shape='$googleLoginShape'
       data-logo_alignment='$googleLoginType'>
 </div>
```

and the js:

```
<script src='accounts.google.com/gsi/client' async defer></script>
```

but when I click on this button I get the expected new window - but it's empty and the console reads: `m=credential_page_library:48 [GSI_LOGGER]: The given origin is not allowed for the given client ID.`

Am I doing something wrong? Am I not allowed to have a dev environment not named localhost?

NOTE: I had this working on a WAMP localhost environment, but since moving to a DEV LAMP with a non localhost URL then this seems to have stopped working.

NOTE2: I have been able to get this to work by making my LAMP environment http://localhost (port 80) (but not http://localhost:81) - but this then presents me with the inability to run multiple different projects as they really want to have different URLs

Comment: Are you doing JavaScript client side or PHP server side

Comment: How do you mean? The php is returning this structure that <script src='https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client' async defer></script> handles (I think)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/68438293/1427878 lists a number of possible reasons / fixes, have you gone through those already?

Comment: Thanks CBroe - but none of these look like they work. I think google must be considering localhost on port 80 is a special case - but I cannot find any way to defined different ports or different local projects. that link shows some people trying different ports on localhost - but I couldn't get that to work through the google login screen.